# How to stream PCM audio on HTML without lag?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, video-streaming, streaming, audio-streaming

The PCM audio data is captured in Unity3D in real time. All those data will be streaming to HTML via WebSockets. The general setup is Socket.IO with node.js server.

My major task is adding smooth audio playback for live video+audio streaming solution on All platform. This is my working progress(video streaming): https://youtu.be/82_-a7WF3vs

The audio & video streaming part works well on non-html/non-WebGL platforms.

However, I couldn't make smooth audio playback on html with javascript. It runs real-time but I found some lagging issue like noise...
One of my concern is that Web Browsers do not support multi-threading, it added some lag when receiving streaming data and playback at the same time.

below is my core script for PCM playback. Hope someone can help me improve it.

```
        var startTime = 0;
        var audioCtx = new AudioContext();

        function ProcessAudioData(_byte) {
            ReadyToGetFrame_aud = false;

            //read meta data
            SourceSampleRate = ByteToInt32(_byte, 0);
            SourceChannels = ByteToInt32(_byte, 4);

            //conver byte[] to float
            var BufferData = _byte.slice(8, _byte.length);
            AudioFloat = new Float32Array(BufferData.buffer);

            //=====================playback=====================
            if(AudioFloat.length > 0) StreamAudio(SourceChannels, AudioFloat.length, SourceSampleRate, AudioFloat);
            //=====================playback=====================

            ReadyToGetFrame_aud = true;
        }

        function StreamAudio(NUM_CHANNELS, NUM_SAMPLES, SAMPLE_RATE, AUDIO_CHUNKS) {
            var audioBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(NUM_CHANNELS, (NUM_SAMPLES / NUM_CHANNELS), SAMPLE_RATE);
            for (var channel = 0; channel < NUM_CHANNELS; channel++) {
                // This gives us the actual ArrayBuffer that contains the data
                var nowBuffering = audioBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
                for (var i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i++) {
                    var order = i * NUM_CHANNELS + channel;
                    nowBuffering[i] = AUDIO_CHUNKS[order];
                }
            }

            var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
            source.buffer = audioBuffer;

            source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
            source.start(startTime);

            startTime += audioBuffer.duration;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to stream PCM audio on HTML without lag?

There is always some lag with digital audio, no matter what you do.  This has nothing to do with the web browser itself.

> All those data will be streaming to HTML via WebSockets.

Why?  The data is only going one direction so you can use a regular HTTP response and not have to worry about the overhead of Web Sockets.

> One of my concern is that Web Browsers do not support multi-threading

This isn't really accurate.

> It runs real-time but I found some lagging issue like noise...

What your code appears to do is take a PCM frame it receives and play it immediately.  This isn't good, as the sound is wrecked if you don't play your received buffers contiguously.  You must take the data and schedule it to play immediately after the current data is finished, and not a sample early or too late.

Traditionally this means doing your own buffering and setting up a ScriptProcessorNode to read from those buffers.  However, this also requires some DIY resampling because the encoded rate may not be the same as the playback rate.

These days, I think that MediaSource Extensions supports PCM decoding, so you can just pipe your data through that and let the underlying system do all the work for you.

Comment: Do you have any example of ScriptProcessorNode? I think i tried it before, but it plays like half speed and delay. Probably the sample rate is different and need a way to resample.

Comment: I have to use WebSockets as I will use it like UDP/TCP communication in my project.